# Determining subsets of two sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I found this question and I just cannot work out the answer, it might be a trick question of some sort because it does not make sense to me.

> For each of the pair of sets $A$ and $B$ below, determine whether $A\subseteq B$ or $B\subseteq A$ or $A = B$.
>
> $A = \{1, 2\}$
>   $B = \{2, 3, 4\}$

I went over all the combinations and can't confirm any of them.

Comment: From your two questions it seems to me that you will benefit **greatly** from reviewing the basic definitions of the basic relations between sets, and the basics of propositional logic. My suggestion to my freshman students is to work with the notes open so the definitions are always in front of you.

Comment: It turns out this question was a typo, it made me doubt everything I thought I knew about set theory for nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that neither of
$$
(\text{a)}\quad A\subseteq B\\
(\text{b)}\quad B\subseteq A\\
(\text{c)}\quad A =B.
$$
are true.

(a) would mean that every element in $A$ is also an element in $B$. $1$ is an element in $A$ but not in $B$.

(b) This is likewise

(c) Note that $A = B$ would *imply* that $A\subseteq B$, so this is also false.

Comment: Just to elaborate on (c), $A=B$ is usually defined to mean that each set is a subset of the other. (By the way, this is not meant for your benefit, Thomas!

Answer (score 2):

Do you know what it means for a set to be a subset of another?

We say that $X \subseteq Y$ if and only if $x \in X \implies x \in Y$.

Note that $1 \in A$ but $1 \notin B$, and $4 \in B$ but $4 \notin A$. So what can you say about the statements $A \subseteq B$ and vice-versa?